# Salesforce OAuth and SalesforceSDK from Forcepad

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ipad

Does anyone here have this particular Salesforce OAuth and SalesforceSDK from Forcepad?

https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad/tree/master/Accounts/util/iOS-SDK

I want to support arm64 for Forcepad base application and that static libraries there only support armv7 and armv7s, the new one [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS)
breaks my build.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, the old oAuth (https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad/tree/master/Accounts/util/iOS-SDK/SalesforceOAuth/Libraries) and SaelsforceSDK lib (https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad/blob/master/Accounts/util/iOS-SDK/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a) are available in the ForcePad repo. What else are you looking for?

Comment: @GauravKheterpal they're not compiled against arm64

Comment: @JHersh may be the best person to guide on this. I would rather focus on fixing issues with the latest lib rather than trying to dig the old libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahoy, I wrote ForcePad in 2010-2011, long before there was an official Mobile SDK, and so I would be highly suspicious of any and all networking code you pull out of the source.

If your goal is to present a ForcePad-like UI on a more modern networking or model stack, or if you want to support arm64, I would recommend swapping out the entire network stack in favor of the latest Mobile SDK. Feel free to send me an electronic mail or PM (or whatever the SO equivalent is) if you have more questions.